# Order picking optimization: creating links between sectors of the warehouse

Tags: optimization, graphs

In the Conference Paper [A Generic Approach for Order Picking Optimization Process in Different Warehouse Layouts](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326610245_A_Generic_Approach_for_Order_Picking_Optimization_Process_in_Different_Warehouse_Layouts), I cannot understand the process described on page 4:

*That is done by creating new links, even between sectors that do not have direct links. It is done in the following way: let $X$ and $Y$ be two nonadjacent sectors, then for each exit $a$ from $X$ and for each entrance $b$ into $Y$, if there exists a path from $a$ to $b$ which does not go through $A$, calculate the distance $d(a, b)$ between $a$ and $b$. Now a link $L$ can be defined as $L = \{X, Y, d(a, b), a, b\}$.*

Now, what is $A$? And what is an exit (from $X$) and an entrance (into $Y$) in this context?

I suppose that, by the definition of a link given on the same page and by the definition of $L$, that $a$ must belong to $X$ and $b$ to $Y$, and that they are two *corresponding pallet places* (using the paper terminology) of existing links of $X$ and other sectors (for $a$) and of $Y$ and other sectors (for $b$), but I have no clue about the meaning of $A$, and it would be helpful if someone could provide a concrete example using *Figure 3* of the paper as reference warehouse.

Also, how can I compute $d(a, b)$ if $a$ and $b$ do NOT belong to neighboring sectors? Until that point, the authors have defined the distance only for points of the same sector or for points in neighboring sectors.

Comment: In four paragraphs prior to the one you took from page 4, they said: "Let x be a  pallet place in sector A  and y  a pallet place in sector B  (A and B are neighboring sectors)."

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but unfortunately it seems not to relate to the $A$ defined in the quoted paragraph, at least to me. If not, please explain the meaning